# Change connected network via VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, networking, windows-7-x64

I want to be able to change my network on the press of a button to another favorite network followed by the launch of a LAN based game and closing a set of pre-defined internet applications that will interrupt gameplay with "Lost connection" popups 
Basically I have two networks, on Internet, one only LAN (Both Wireless)
I want to be able to switch networks and launch my game.  I know the code for launching my game, but my question is....
How do I switch network connections using my program?  Or is it even possible?

Comment: What do  you mean by "change network"? Do you mean disable one network and enable another? Why would you need to disconnect a LAN just to use the internet? What operating system?

Comment: I have two wireless networks.  
One I use for LAN gaming so that it doesn't steal bandwidth for others, the other is a shared one.  

My goal is to disconnect from one (internet) and connect to the other (non-internet). Basically I want to save myself the extra step of having to manually switch.  
The (legacy) game takes a long time to open, and won't look for new connections after it is open. So I am also trying to prevent against forgetfulness while making everything more streamline to run the program. 

I am using Windows 7 x64 (See Tags)
My hope is to be able to do this in VB, C# works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article about [Native WiFi Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms706274%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Just use the built-in Windows Functions to disconnect / connect

Comment: That looks like what I need to do, but how would I plug that into a VB project? (I'm new at programming)
Another option would be the ability to do it from the command line.